# breeze 1.3.6 cannot get metadata

Tags: breeze, hottowel

The [Devcurry hottowelsignalr example](https://github.com/dotnetcurry/signalr-hot-towel/tree/master/OnlineCollaborationWithSignalR) which utilizes breeze works fine until i upgraded  breeze via nuget to 1.3.6.

F12 in chrome shows that it is trying to retrieve metadata from `http://localhost/api/breeze/Metadata` whereas previously it would use
`http://localhost/OnlineCollaborationWithSignalR/api/breeze/Metadata`. Which is the correct location of the call. It appears that the path of the application  is missing from the root. i.e. (**OnlineCollaborationWithSignalR**)

**Update**
  noticed the release notes for 1.3.1. And subsequently changed the routing to

```
public static class BreezeWebApiConfig {

    public static void RegisterBreezePreStart() {
      GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "BreezeApi",
          routeTemplate: "breeze/{controller}/{action}"
      );
    }
  }
```

and the app/viewmodels/home.js to

```
  // service name is route to the Web API controller
    var serviceName = 'breeze/Breeze';

 from
  // service name is route to the Web API controller
    var serviceName = 'api/Breeze';
```

It still fails with the same error as noted above.

Answer (score 2):

Can you confirm that the API responds accordingly?

Based on your routeTemplate, it should be.

`http://localhost/breeze/Breeze/Metadata`

UPDATE:

Yes, if your configuration is such. It should be

`http://localhost/OnlineCollaborationWithSignalR/breeze/Breeze/Metadata`

I am not familiar with the specific project, but I downloaded and updated it. I then made the changes that you specified, and I am getting a response from the API. Although I am getting an error (most likely unrelated), it is in fact routed properly.

For the record, the error I get is:

`"The provider for invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' is specified multiple times in the application configuration. The invariant name must be unique for each configured provider."`

Comment: from my understanding of mvc/webapi routeconfig since my application runs from http://localhost/OnlineCollaborationWithSignalR/ that route should be http://localhost/OnlineCollaborationWithSignalR/breeze/Breeze/Metadata

Comment: i suspect your SQL issue is related to you changing to use SQLExpress, when i changed to use IIS rather than vs2012's iisexpress it prompts ou to use sqlexpress rather than localdb.  IVe tried again from scratch and still getting the metadata error, as it tried to request the resource from the iis root rather than the deployed location.